# query to Sum product of two tables

Tags: sql, database, sap-iq

I have a 2 tables with names and balances ex

Table A

```
  Name    | Amount
-----------------------                           
  Abraham | 500  
  Abraham | 100  
  George  | -200  
  George  | 200  
  Thomas  | 300  
  Thomas  | -100
```

Table B

```
  Name    | Amount
-------------------------                           
  Abraham | 100  
  Abraham | 200  
  George  | -200  
  George  | 50  
  Thomas  | 400  
  Thomas  | 300   
  Albert  | -100       
  Albert  | -200
```

So I need to add the 2 tables up , every name has a positive and a negative, I dont know if Table A and table B will have the same amount of unique names or not so it could be either or. 
When I run the query

```
Select sum(Amount)  
from table_A  
group by Name
```

This query Works for either  Table A or Table B individually but when I try to run a query like this I get an outrageous number

```
Select a.Name , sum(a.amount) + sum(b.amount)
from table_A full outer join table_B b on a.Name = b.Name
group by a.Name
```

is there a way to do this in one query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My query works fine using `UNION ALL`. See my query and SQL Fiddle Demo below:

```
SELECT Name,SUM(Amount)Amount FROM(
SELECT Name, Amount
    FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, Amount
    FROM TableB) AS A GROUP BY Name
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3d56/14/0)**

Answer (score 0):

**In ORACLE I would do**

```
SELECT Name, sum(Amount) AS Amount FROM
  (SELECT Name, Amount
    FROM table_A  
UNION ALL
  SELECT Name, Amount
    FROM table_B  )
GROUP BY Name
```

Try if it is possible to do something similar in sybase.

And from in-line view I would make "real" view.

**If I did not understand your intentions I am very sorry.**

Comment: I wrote SQL "from head" and I made this stupid mistake. Thanks for correcting me Fred.

Answer (score 0):

To use a join, you'll need to avoid the Cartesian product you're currently encountering by summarizing each table in a separate expression, such as the nested subqueries shown below:

```
SELECT aa.name, COALESCE(aa.amount,0) + COALESCE (bb.amount,0)
FROM ( 
      SELECT a.name, SUM(a.amount) AS amount 
      FROM TableA a GROUP BY a.name
 ) aa
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
      SELECT b.name, SUM(b.amount) AS amount 
      FROM TableB b GROUP BY b.name
 ) bb
ON aa.name = bb.name
;
```